# Set world coordinate system origin to a new location?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft creative mode, is there any way to set the 0,0,0 origin point of the coordinate system to a specific location?

It would make the mental arithmetic much more convenient when I am building stuff with lots of `/fill` and `/copyblocks`. Right now, I am writing down the coordinates of reference points, and offsetting everything by their coordinates, every time. What I would like, would be to be able to refer to the north-west corner of a structure that I am building as `0,0,0`, and the far corner as `$width,$height,$length`.

I'm on PC, v1.10.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no way to do exactly that, you could place an armor stand with a tag or name on the new origin:

`/summon armor_stand X Y Z {Tags:["origin"]}`

Then you can use the following command to use this as origin:

`/execute @e[tag=origin] ~ ~ ~ <your command>`

Comment: With `/execute ...` in recent history, this is fairly convenient. Looks like the MC CLI has more potential than I realized, the manual might be worth a full read through...